# Random User Name

Tags: php, random

Here is the situation, I have registration page that allows user to signup but only allows for the user to enter their first name, last name email and password. The data is stored in a temp user table, this is for users that haven't yet activated their account.

After a successful registration the user may activate their account with an email and once activated the data is moved to a different table and removed from the temp table.(I know some may disagree with this method, but this is the method I've chosen).  All this works good.

The problem I'm facing now is, I have a field that is for a username, this is really only used for building URL's like so: example.com/home/first.last.56 but it must be unique and of course the user will be able to later change this once active and logged in.

I know this would be easier if I just allowed the user to select their own username and probably simpler in the long run, however for the time being this isn't want I want to do.

**Things I have thought about doing:**

Using the unique row id from the "temp table" and placing on the end of the string like so: first.last.56 where first and last are the users first and last name and 56 is the unique row id from the temp table. This works ok but im thinking that once the table grows to say 1500 or 2000 then the username will be long i.e. first.last.1597 and a bit of an eye-sore in terms of the way the url looks and also the url is not very user friendly. I would like to keep this to a 2 digit MAXIMUM.

What are some other methods for achieving this, while maintaining a unique user name?

Also im ok with using letters form the first name or last name to create the user name as long as the name is similar to the users real name.

Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
    $new_member_insert_data = array(
        'First_Name' => ucfirst(strtolower($first_name)),
        'Last_Name' => ucfirst(strtolower($last_name)),
        'Email' => $this->input->post($this->session->userdata('email_n_attribute')),
        'Password' => $hash,
        'Confirm_Code' => $confirm_code,
        'IP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );
    
    $insert = $this->db->insert('Temp_Account', $new_member_insert_data);
    
    $this->db->select('idAccount');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('Temp_Account', $new_member_insert_data);
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $user_name = array('User_Name' => $first_name.'.'.$last_name.'.'.$row->idAccount);
            $this->db->where('idAccount', $row->idAccount);
            $this->db->update('Temp_Account', $user_name);  
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Can you have, like, 1000+ John Does?

Comment: check to see if a record with the same first and last exists? if so count how many and add 1. First John Doe = john.doe.1 Second John Doe = john.doe.2

Comment: You can also convert the ID to Base64 instead of Base10 which will keep it shorter. I also agree with the above - check to see if the it is a duplicate before adding any numbers.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait before i responded, posted right before I left for work. @Pitchinnate Yea that seems to be a good logical method for handling this, as I expect most users to change their username once logged in. If it isn't to much, could you give an example of how the mysql would look? I'm using codeigniter framework. Thanks!

Comment: @SalmanA The odds are probably not, however I feel that you should always avoid any chance of collision when dealing with database, in the off chance that it could happen. Also just seems like good coding practice to make sure that it isn't a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to thank everyone for the feedback and say that stackoverflow.com is awesome and has the best community! Ever.

So after doing some toying around, several failed attempts, and the advice form comments left from above this is what I have come up with.

I decided to just create a private function that handles the creation of the "random user name". At first I tried writing the sql portion using the MySQL COUNT() function, to realize that this isn't needed. (When using Active record with Codeignter)

Instead you can simply query the database and check for a result like so,

```
    $sql = 'SELECT User_Name FROM Account WHERE User_Name = ?';
    $count = $this->db->query($sql, $user_name);
```

So here is the random_user_name function:

```
private function random_user_name($first_name, $last_name, $data){
    // Generate a random number
    $rand_number = rand(2, 99);
    // Create the username 
    $user_name = array('User_Name' => $first_name.'.'.$last_name.'.'.$rand_number);

    // Check the db for a matching username     
    $sql = 'SELECT User_Name FROM Account WHERE User_Name = ?';
    $count = $this->db->query($sql, $user_name);

    // If a matching username is found run the function again, to create a new username 
    if($count->num_rows() == 1){
            $this->random_user_name($first_name, $last_name, $data);
    }else{

        // Select the row id from the db of the newly created user  
        $this->db->select('idAccount');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('Temp_Account', $data);

        // If we find the user, and we better! update the username field
        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            foreach($query->result() as $row){  
                $this->db->where('idAccount', $row->idAccount);
                $this->db->update('Temp_Account', $user_name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else from spending more time than necessary trying to figure what turned out to be a fairly simple problem, and again thanks everyone!

Comment: And as always im open to better or improved solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I've personally never used the codeigniter  framework but here is how I would do it:

```
$search_user_name = $first_name.'.'.$last_name.'.';
$query = "select count(1) as count from users where User_Name like '{$search_user_name }%'";
//Use whatever DB method you CI uses to run this query
//If possible remove $user_name from the query directly and use bind parameter
//This query will return a number ($count) then you can do the following
$user_name = array('User_Name' => $search_user_name . $count);
//Use the rest of your existing code
```

Comment: Just to clarify, basically I would use the counted number for the user number rather than a randomly generated number?

Comment: correct, it will be the value you receive when you run `$query`

Comment: Sorry for the delay in a response, school and work! LOL, this seems to be a good method and may actually be a little faster than the use of the random number method. I will give a try when I get a chance. Thanks!